# Correct HTTP method to use when handling documents in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, mean-stack

I have a mean web app.
I used a MongoDB document for each one of my users.
I was wondering about which HTTP method to use for handling the documents.

For example, when I do push to an array in MongoDB document, should I use PATCH, PUT, POST?
When I remove an item from an array, should I use PATCH, PUT, DELETE?

What is the general idea here?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html

Comment: This page was opened on another tab in my browser :) but it doesn't answer the question...

Comment: It does answer the question. Each method depends on the request type depending on if its an update/replace. Ie: If you want to update a document, do a PATCH but the body should only include the changes (not the entire document). To create a new document, use POST. Look at the PUT specification below the table on when to use it for an update or replace.

Comment: So what would you use to remove an item from a document? PATCH? Thanks

Comment: @EdgarBarber You should use DELETE

Answer (score 0):

1. GET: Get a resource
2. POST: Create a resource
3. PUT: Replaces (Updates) a ressource
4. PATCH: Modify/Alter a resource (change part of existing resource)
5. DELETE: Delete a resource

I hope this will help you.